# What happened to DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges in EF 4.3?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

By removing EdmMetadata table in EF 4.3, It seems **DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges** no longer works. does it?

OR

Is there a way to declare initializer as I do in SEED method of EF 4.2 ?

Comment: what do you mean 'does not work by eliminating EdmMetadata table'? DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges has always deleted the whole DB if it detects a difference between EdmMetadata and the code based schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EdmMetadata` is obsoleted in EF 4.3 Code First models, instead it use `_MigrationHistory` table to check compatibility between Model and Database.

(Note that the _MigrationHistory table is made a system table if possible. This means that to see it you may need to expand the “System Tables” in SQL Management Studio or your preferred tool.)

In EF 4.3, when DbContext is used with the Code First approach, `Database.Create` attempts to use Code First Migrations to create the database and perform DDL. `Database.Create` performs an initial automatic migration for you. As part of this process, migrations will create a table called `_MigrationHistory` and insert a row into this table containing a compressed version of your Code First model.  And **DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges** initializers use the `Database.CompatibleWithModel` method to determine whether or not the Code First model matches the model that was used to create the database by checking **_MigrationHistory** table.

http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/01/13/ef-4-3-beta-1-what-happened-to-that-edmmetadata-table/

Comment: First thank you for your useful answer,But I already know about Migrations and _MgrationHistory table,The main problem is initial records that in EF 4.2 I could insert to DB.(Before going on EF 4.3 when I change Model I could insert some sample records to DB by overriding the **Seed** method) What is the solution for it in EF 4.3?

Comment: You can still override in Seed method of CreateDatabaseIfNotExists or DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges as in EF 4.2. But your old data will be lost if use with DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges. To preserve old data in EF 4.3, use AddOrUpdate in Seed method of Configuration class.